# Copy 2d array of structs to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I have something like that:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PixelColorRGBA
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 ColorBGRA;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Blue;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Green;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Red;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Alpha;
}
```

What is the fastest way to copy `PixelColorRGBA[w, h]` to `byte[w * h * 4]` and vise versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with the following code:

```
var source = new PixelColorRGBA[1000, 1000];
var destination = new byte[4000000];
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    unsafe
    {
        for (var q = 0; q < 100; q++)
            fixed (PixelColorRGBA* tmpSourcePtr = &source[0, 0])
            {
                var sourcePtr = (IntPtr) tmpSourcePtr;
                Marshal.Copy(sourcePtr, destination, 0, 4000000);
            }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("MS: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

It takes 62 ms on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
    PixelColorRGBA[,] source = ...;
    byte[] dest = source
        .Cast<PixelColorRGBA>()
        .SelectMany(x => new byte[] { x.Blue, x.Green, x.Red, x.Alpha })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: @breethe it's the fastest to type ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(myArray, 0, byteArray, 0, length)
```

or

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(myArray, 0, destPtr, length);
```